# Acceder a una propiedad de un JSON

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs

tengo el siguiente JSON

```
"values": [
        ["Martes", "pan", [8, [4],[0]], 7.381498329613434]
    ]
}
```

Cual sería lo forma de mostrar el valor: 7.381498329613434 en mi consola de Javascript?

Muchas gracias

Comment: La respuesta sería: jsonvar["values"][0][3]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para acceder a dicho valor primero debes acceder al objeto que lo contiene en este caso **values**

```
    data={"values": [
            ["Martes", "pan", [8, [4],[0]], 7.381498329613434]
        ]
    }

    values = data.values;
    arr_values = values[0]
    console.log(arr_values[3]);
```

como te puedes fijar asigno a una variable llamada values el objeto que contiene mi valor deseado.

Con dicha asignacion obtengo un array:

[image: array]

Para obtener el valor deseado tan solo me dirijo a la posicion deseada en este caso 3

```
arr_values[3]
```

y alli tendrias tu resultado:

[image: result]

Espero te sirva y te ayude.!!

Answer (score 4):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
var obj = {"values": [
        ["Martes", "pan", [8, [4],[0]], 7.381498329613434]
    ]
}

console.log(obj.values[0][3]);
```